# How to handle unmanaged Win32 exception from C#

Tags: c#, c++, exception

Hi guys I'm trying to figure out whether it is possible to catch(or at least suppress) all kinds of unmanaged exceptions in managed code? I've seen a lot of questions here already but it is still unclear for me, what types of exceptions are catchable and what are not?

Just as an example i've made a C++ programm that performs division by zero:

```
printf("Hello from unmanaged code\n");
int a = 0;
printf("%d\n", 10 / a);
return 0;
```

And a C# application

```
        try
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "test.exe";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("success");
        }
        catch (Win32Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        }
        catch(ExternalException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3");
        }
```

None of the catchs here does not trigger, program termintaion window appeares and after closing it, C# programm continues normal execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of language or catch-block-usage, *you cannot handle exceptions from different processes*.

Comment: Yes, and the C++ program is responsible for catching and reporting its own exceptions, and not expect other processes to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by nvoigt you can not handle exception in this case. a more suitable solution for this case is reading the returned value from C++ code. for example : 
    if (a != 0) return 1;
then handling it in your C# code like:
   if (p.ExitCode == 1) Console.WriteLine("division by zero");